# Oracle | If row not found then output count 0

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a list of client names (comma separated) I need to find out how many exists in Client table and how many dont.
The table and input lists are both huge; here I'm just giving table as an example of my requirement.

Client

| client_name | status |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| def | 1 |
| ghi | 0 |
| jkl | 1 |

Query I thought of using is

```
select client_name, count(client_name) over (partition by client_name) count_client from client where status = 1 and client_name in ('abc', 'xyz', 'ghi', 'jkl');
```

This returns:

| client_name | count_client |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| jkl | 1 |

But what I need is

| client_name | count_client |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| xyz | 0 |
| ghi | 0 |
| jkl | 1 |

Could someone please help me with the SQL query

Comment: Turn the CSV into a list of values and then left join the table data to the values list, group and count. COUNT() will then count the nulls where the left join failed, as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "huge" amount of data, then your best option is to store list of values you're interested in into a separate table. That's trivial.

Otherwise, as an alternative you could try something like this (sample data in lines #1 - 11; query begins at line #12):

```
SQL> WITH
  2     client (client_name, status)
  3     AS
  4        -- this is contents of your table
  5        (SELECT 'abc', 1 FROM DUAL
  6         UNION ALL
  7         SELECT 'def', 1 FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT 'ghi', 0 FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 'jkl', 1 FROM DUAL)
 12    -- join your table with a collection
 13    SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE AS client_name, NVL (SUM (c.status), 0) AS count_client
 14      FROM client c
 15           RIGHT JOIN TABLE (sys.odcivarchar2list ('abc',
 16                                                   'xyz',
 17                                                   'ghi',
 18                                                   'jkl')) t
 19              ON     t.COLUMN_VALUE = c.client_name
 20                 AND c.status = 1
 21  GROUP BY t.COLUMN_VALUE
 22  ORDER BY t.COLUMN_VALUE;

CLIENT_NAME     COUNT_CLIENT
--------------- ------------
abc                        1
ghi                        0
jkl                        1
xyz                        0

SQL>
```

Comment: Using TABLE (sys.odcivarchar2list ('abc','xyz','ghi','jkl') worked like charm. Thank you @Littlefoot

Comment: Aha, see? @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally maintain a separate table containing the client names of interest.  Absent that, we can use a CTE to store the values, then left join to your current table:

```sql
WITH clients AS (
    SELECT 'abc' AS client_name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xyz' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ghi' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jkl' FROM dual
)

SELECT cl.client_name, COUNT(c.client_name) AS count_client
FROM clients cl
LEFT JOIN client c
    ON c.client_name = cl.client_name AND
       c.status = 1
GROUP BY cl.client_name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I know about this approach but I was wondering if there is any other way?

Comment: @hnadiger Yes, as I suggested, replace my CTE with a bona-fide table containing all these values.

Comment: Thanks @Time Biegeleien but I'm going to consider solution given by Littlefoot. Your solution also works so I'll upvote it.

Comment: ...and the best answer isn't always the one which gets accepted on this site ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and also, SO's lack of coordination notifications causes a huge amount of wasted time for contributors; yours and LF's answers were probably being created simultaneosuly and are effectively equivalent. I know for one that if I saw SO notify me "Tim Biegeliesen and Littlefoot are writing answers to this question", I'd know I wouldn't need to start writing one too!

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually, if I landed here and saw that Littlefoot had already given his answer, I would have just moved on.

Comment: Ye, though I'm talking about that simultaneity - there's only 6 mins between yours and LF's so I think it quite likely LF started while yours was still being written (unless you really did knock this out in 6 mins, which is good going) - if there was a "Tim is writing" banner, I wouldn't start (and I suspect neither would LF).. Just my idle grumble that through a lack of "dot dot dot x is writing.." thousands of hours of professional time is wasted that could be better spread among other questions